# Iteration hash Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this half working half broken code here.

```
hash = upcase.scan(/\w/).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |char, hash|
  hash[char] += 1
end 
hash.each do |key, value|
  puts "#{key}: #{value.times{print"x"}}" 
end
```

Which returns something like this.

```
xH: 1
xE: 1
xxL: 2
xO: 1

=> {"H"=>1, "E"=>1, "L"=>2, "O"=>1}
```

My question how can I make the code print out the "x"'s after

```
#{key}:
```

instead of the number.

And also I like to know how is it possible to return nothing instead of the last line?

```
=> {"H"=>1, "E"=>1, "L"=>2, "O"=>1}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It "returns" something because `each` returns whatever you're iterating over. If you run this in `irb` it prints the result of the last statement by default. Also, consider just doing something like `"#{key}: #{'x'*value}"` to make things easier to read, and avoid printing the return value of `times`, which has the same issue you're seeing overall.

Comment: Did you mean to write `hash = str.upcase.scan...`? If not, then presumably you are adding a method to the class `String`, in which case you should display your code enclosed in `def my_method...end` and that enclosed in `class String...end`.

Comment: Indeed I added to the String class. I thought it was not going to be problem to answer my question and indeed it wasn't. :-)

Comment: Perhaps, but at the least, you should say that what you have written is part of a method you are writing for the `String` class. Many readers will make that assumption, but I assure you that many others—Ruby newbies especially—will not. In any event, I can't think of an argument for omitting those few words.

Comment: I will keep that in mind for the next time. Anyhow thank you again for everyone's time on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line

```
puts "#{key}: #{value.times{print"x"}}"
```

to

```
puts "#{key}: #{'x' * value}"
```

It works, because in Ruby [`String` * `int` will repeat the `String` `int` times](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-2A).

In your version of the code, the `print ...` was evaluated (and printed to the console) before the `puts` got to display anything, and that's why you got that seemingly weird behavior.

Comment: @user4274735 if you want to avoid `each_with_object` you can also construct your histogram hash using `group_by`: `hash = Hash[upcase.scan(/\w/).group_by{|c| c }.map{|k,v| [k, v.count]} ]`. Use whichever you find more readable.